# How to delete a single instance from a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to delete a single instance from a database query. "l.remove" represents what i want to do but i know its wrong. I have tried delete and destroy. destroy didn't work and delete actually removed the data from the database. I just want the data removed from the variable. Can anyone help me?

```
<%
        @owner = User.find(params[:id])
        @job_list = ShoppingList.where(:user_id=>@user.user_id)

        @job_list.each do |l|
            @temp = FlaggedCandidate.where(:flagged_user_id=>@owner.user_id, :list_id=>l.list_id)

            if !@temp.nil?
                l.remove
            end
        end

        @candidate = FlaggedCandidate.new   

    %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the code i assume that User has many ShoppingList.

You can do something like:

```
@job_list = @owner.shopping_lists.where( list_id: FlaggedCandidate.where( flagged_user_id: @owner.user_id ).pluck(:list_id) )
```

That could save the trouble of looping around.

Comment: Note to other people though, this does not solve the posted question but it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to remove record from db. In order to just modify collection `@job_list` you need reject some unsatisfied elements. You can do it with [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) method (to select job_lists that flagged), or [`reject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-reject) in opposite. This is how you code should looks like:

```
@owner = User.find(params[:id])
@job_list = ShoppingList.where(:user_id=>@user.user_id)

@job_list.select! do |job_list|
  FlaggedCandidate.where(
      :flagged_user_id => @owner.user_id,
      :list_id => job_list.list_id
  ).any?
end

@candidate = FlaggedCandidate.new
```

`select!` simply change the original collection, instead of doing `@job_list = @job_list.select { ... }`

Comment: i says that "remove" in undefined

Comment: its not crashing on me but i am getting nothing as output. I am trying to display the the job_list like this.

<%= f.collection_select(:list_id,  @job_list, :list_id, :name) %>

i don't know enough about your code to be able to alter it myself. although the top one makes sense if it is an if statement before the do. (sorry about my ealier post, i forgot to refresh the page)

Comment: is there maybe a way to build a new job_list? I just tried 

if temp.nil?
 final += l
end

within the .each loop. In my form for when i use final. it says its nil but do you think i have the right idea?

Comment: if you are reffering to mine. it did not work. it gave me nil

Comment: No, he's talking to me. I explained, but a can't understand what the problem now. It will be great if you update the question with error of relevant information.